# Does "for all but a finite number~" mean that a domain is infinite??

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying linear algebra and I have a problem.

Let $S$ be a nonempty set, and $F$ a field. Let $C(S,F)$ denote the set of all functions

such that $f(s) = 0$ *for all but a finite number of elements* of $S$.

Prove that $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $F(S,F)$.($S$ is domain, and $F$ is codomain)

In this problem, the problem just says $S$ is nonempty.

IF $S$ is finite, then let $S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$

and let $f(s_1)=0 ,f(s_2)=0, f(s_3)=3 ,  g(s_1)=1, g(s_2)=1, g(s_3)=0$.

then $f,g$ have a finite number of nonzero elements of $S$ but $f+g$ has not a single zero point.

so $f+g$ is not in $C(S,F)$

In this problem, does $S$ should be infinite??

Comment: In your example, $f+g$ is indeed $0$ for all but finitely many elements of $S$.

Comment: none is still finite

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $S$ is finite, then ''almost all'' has no effect.

It has an effect when $S$ is infinite.
Then a function $f:S\rightarrow F$ in which almost all image values are $0$ has only finitely many elements $s\in S$ with $f(s)\ne 0$.

The set $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $F(S,F)$ in your notation. Indeed:

First, it a subset.

Second, if $f,g\in C(S,F)$, then $(f+g)(s) = f(s)+g(s)$ and so by hypothesis it is easy to see that $f+g\in C(S,F)$.

Third, if $f\in C(S,F)$ and $a\in F$, then $(a\cdot f)(s) = a f(s)$ and so by hypothesis $a\cdot f\in C(S,F)$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is easy to see the case when $S$ is finite since the number of $f(s)$ is also finite. In fact, your  example $f+g$ is actually in $C(S,F)$. Since you have finite number of nonzeroes.

I believe your confusion is the understanding of the phrase itself.
Note:

$f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$ means that there are finite number of nonzeroes, others are all zeroes. It is easier to understand using $n$-tuples example where we have $(f(s_1), f(s_2), f(s_3), \ldots, f(s_n))$ for finite case, or $(f(s_1), f(s_2), f(s_3), \ldots)$ for infinite case.

(1,2,3,4,5,0,0,6,0,0,0,0) A case where you have finite number of nonzeroes and zeroes and it still satisfies $f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$.

(1,2,3,4,5,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,...) A case where you have finite number of nonzeroes and infinite number of zeroes and it still satisfies $f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$.

To answer the query directly, $S$ may not necessarily mean infinite in your case. Although it is a good point to use the phrase "for all but a finite number" when dealing with some infinite set.